# Group By de 1 Coluna SQL Oracle com data mais recente

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Tenho uma tabela (TVIC_ODS_MVEL_PRQE), no ORACLE SQL, com milhões de registros e preciso extrair dela apenas 2 colunas: número de telefone (NU_TLFN) e data (DT_PRMR_ATVC_LNHA).
O problema é que eu preciso só de números de telefones sem duplicatas e apenas a data mais recente. Só que há valores duplicados em ambas colunas, por exemplo:

```
|  NU_TLFN  | DT_PRMR_ATVC_LNHA |
|11911111111|     24/08/2021    |
|11911111111|     24/08/2021    |
|11911111111|     25/08/2021    |
|11922222222|     21/08/2021    |
|11922222222|     22/08/2021    |
|11922222222|     22/08/2021    |
```

E eu preciso de um select que me traga apenas 1 registro por número de telefone com a data mais recente. Exemplo do resultado esperado:

```
|  NU_TLFN  | DT_PRMR_ATVC_LNHA |
|11911111111|     25/08/2021    |
|11922222222|     22/08/2021    |
```

Tentei fazer o select dessa forma:

```
select distinct NU_TLFN, DT_PRMR_ATVC_LNHA from TVIC_ODS_MVEL_PRQE
where NU_ANO_MES in ('202105','202106','202107','202108')
group by NU_TLFN
order by DT_PRMR_ATVC_LNHA desc
```

Sendo o where a restricao da análise (a partir de Maio) com coluna NU_ANO_MES mostrando os meses.

Porém o select dá erro no Group By e só roda se eu colocar group by NU_TLFN, DT_PRMR_ATVC_LNHA. Mas por ter duplicatas em ambas colunas, não resolve o problema.

Alguma ideia de como resolver?

PS: Infelizmente não há coluna id na tabela

Comment: Seu banco não tem algo semelhante ao rowid? Tentou com tabelas temporárias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Porém o select dá erro no Group By e só roda se eu colocar group by NU_TLFN"* extamtente. Ao usar `GROUP BY` todos os campos do `SELECT` devem ser agrupados ou usar funções de agregação, como `SUM` e `MAX`.

Diferente do `MySQL` que aceita campos fora do `GROUP BY`, no `Oracle` é obrigatório.

Pode então agrupar pelo "NU_TLFN", para remover os duplicados, e usar `MAX(DT_PRMR_ATVC_LNHA)` para pegar a data mais recente, assim:

```
select NU_TLFN, MAX(DT_PRMR_ATVC_LNHA)
  from TVIC_ODS_MVEL_PRQE
 group by NU_TLFN;
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba5f5/1)